# User Registration Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Im trying to implement the built user Authentication/Registration in laravel 5.1 but it keeps redirecting to /home.

Heres the route:

```
Route::post('sign_up' , 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

Form

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/sign_up" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">
```

The postRegister function is commented out so its should not go anywhere:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
//        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
//
//        if ($validator->fails()) {
//            $this->throwValidationException(
//                $request, $validator
//            );
//        }
//
//        Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));
//
//        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the real logic is happening in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait which is placed in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` namespace.

And if you open that you will notice the responsible method `loginPath()` of checking the existence of a `loginPath` attribute which is responsible of redirection back to login route/view.

To change the redirection process add this property to your `AuthController.php` :

`protected $loginPath = "/"; // redirect to where you want`

Or perhaps you want to redirect within your `postRegister()` upon role or some other condition, you may do it like code below, which is btw the dirty road or let's say not taking advantage of Laravel 5.1 new [authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#policies) feature:

```php
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    // Change your loginPath here if you want: $this->loginPath = "/";

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

And it is worth mentioning that the other parallel property is `$redirectTo` which it's used to **redirect to** after successful login attempt, you may add it to your `authController.php`, i.e: again you should use policies to redirect admins only to dashboard and maybe normal users to profile or home!

`protected $redirectTo = "dashboard";`

**Minor tweak:** in your case

you might want to change links to dynamic so please form header make it like this:

`<form method="POST" action="{{ action('Auth\AuthController@postRegister') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">`